# How to avoid special comments in Rhapsody code generation?

Tags: code-generation, rhapsody

When I generate code with Rhapsody, it puts some special comments into the generated files starting with `//##` and containing mostly references to the original elements in the model. From my understanding, these comments are needed for roundtrip feature. When I don't need roundtripping, is there a possibility to avoid generating these special comments (as I think they make the output files much less readable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the annotations, you can set all the `MarkPrologEpilogInAnnotations` properties and the `SimplifyAnnotations` property to `None`.

Example:

```
C_CG::ModelElement::SimplifyAnnotations = None
C_CG::Class::MarkPrologEpilogInAnnotations = None
```